# X and Y axis labels for Bokeh figure

Tags: python, bokeh

Does anyone know how to add x and y axis title/labels for a Bokeh figure? E.g. X-axis: time, Y-axis: stock price.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 52):

As of Bokeh 0.11.1, the [user's guide section on axes](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#axes) now shows how to edit properties of existing axes. The way to do it is the same as before:

```
p = figure(width=300, height=300, x_axis_label='Initial xlabel')
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'New xlabel'
```

Comment: There is also quite a bit of information in the users guide now: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#axes

Answer (score 8):

Check out this example: [elements.py](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/elements.html)

You can also now give general plot related options (`plot_width`, `title`, etc.) to a call to `figure(...)` instead of the renderer function (`circle`, in that example)

Comment: For completeness: if `p = figure()`, then `p.xaxis.axis_label = "foo"` sets the label of the x-axis to `foo`.

Answer (score 7):

This is how you can change the axis label using `CustomJS`:

```py
p = figure(x_axis_label="Initial y-axis label",
           y_axis_label="Initial x-axis label")

# ...

# p.xaxis and p.yaxis are lists. To operate on actual the axes,
# we need to extract them from the lists first.
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(xaxis=p.xaxis[0],
                              yaxis=p.yaxis[0]), code="""
    xaxis.axis_label = "Updated x-axis label";
    yaxis.axis_label = "Updated y-axis label";
""")
```

Comment: @tuomastic none of this complication (extra axis, changing visibility) is necessary to change an axis from a CustomJS. See https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/how-to-get-a-drop-down-to-change-axes-i-thought-this-would-work-but-i-dont-understand-why-not/4522/11?u=bryan

Comment: @bigreddot Thanks for the heads-up. I have updated the answer to include the suggested approach. It would be more intuitive for the Bokeh users if `p.xaxis` and `p.yaxis` were in the plural form: `p.xaxes` and `p.yaxes`.

Answer (score 4):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models.annotations import Title
p = figure(plot_width=1300, plot_height=400,x_axis_type="datetime")
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Time'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Stock Price'
p.line(time,stock_price)
t = Title()
t.text = 'Stock Price during year 2018'
p.title = t
show(p)
```